# Joomla menu issue to show current item

Tags: php, joomla

I have two different menus in my Joomla site. One is top menu with menu items (Home, Portfolio, contact us etc) and the 2nd is a left menu with menu items (p1, p2, p3 etc). I created different menus for both top menu and left menu. Now what I want is when I select "Portfolio" from top menu it should displayed as current item and "p1" (from left menu) should also be current. Also, in the same way when I select any of the menu item from left menu the portfolio must remain selected (current).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using menu aliases.

In your second menu, change each of the menu item's type to `alias`. Doing that will give you an option of selecting a menu item from the main menu. Select the corresponding main menu item and save.

Now when you click a menu item in either menu, the corresponding item in the other menu will be active along with the one that you clicked on.